# Cannot create non-empty csr.matrix() in scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, scipy

I need sparse matrix to solve problem and according to description of scr.matrix() in scipy here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix it fits perfectly for my issue.
However I cannot even initialize it.
When I use empty matrix example from this doc http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html it works fine, exactly as in doc

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> csr_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8).toarray()
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

but when I use example of non-empty martix or try to fill it with my own data

```
>>> row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
>>> col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
```

I always got this message

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-macosx-10.10-
intel.egg/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2507: VisibleDeprecationWarning: 
`rank` is deprecated; use the `ndim` attribute or function instead. 
 To find the rank of a matrix see `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`.
 VisibleDeprecationWarning)
```

What does it mean? I completely stuck. Excuse me for that question I'm new to scipy and need help.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error; as far as I can tell, your code should run fine otherwise. It appears parts of scipy have not been upgraded to use new adjustments in the numpy library. Have you checked that the resulting matrix you get is incorrect?

Comment: Rather than .toarray() follow the example and view your matrix with .todense()

Comment: @Evert yep, resulting matrix looks ok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only a warning, your matrix I expect to be created.
Scipy is caling an old numpy function. It was fixed in April 2014 in scipy.

Scipy changes at:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/fa1782e04fdab91f672ccf7a4ebfb887de50f01c

Comment: You're right, thank you! Now the strange thing is that I've just updated my scipy using pip and it still has that problem. And when I i check version of scipy using `scipy.__version__` I got 0.13.0b1 but in the **PyCharm Preferences>Project Interpreter** version name is 0.15.1

Comment: Your example works in with `numpy` 1.8.2, `scipy` 1.14.